# How to work after getting a message from the Springboot STOMP chat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, stomp

I'm using STOMP as a springboot to develop a group chat room function for clubs and members, but I posted to ask because there was a blockage!

I can send and receive messages well, but furthermore, when the recipient enters the chat room and receives a message, I want to update the recipient's last_read_chat_id (the last chat message ID read in that chat room) to the latest chat ID.

Can I get some advice on how to handle it after receiving the message? I'd appreciate your help!!

Below is the message transmission code I wrote. (It works fine.)

[Websocket config code]

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketBrokerConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) { // Client에서 websocket연결할 때 사용할 API 경로를 설정
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws/chat")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/sub");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pub");
    }
}
```

[Code for sending a chat message]

```java
@MessageMapping("/chat/message")
    public ResponseEntity sendChatMessage(
            @RequestBody ChatDto chatDto
    ) {
        // senderName
        String senderName = "";
        if (chatDto.getCrewId() != null && chatDto.getUserId() == null) { // Sender = crew
            senderName = crewService.findCrewNameByCrewId(chatDto.getCrewId());
        } else { // Sender = user
            senderName = "User";
            Integer enterOrder = userChatRoomService.findEnterOrderByUserIdAndChatRoomId(chatDto.getUserId(), chatDto.getChatRoomId());
            senderName += enterOrder;
        }

        // Dto to Entity
        Chat chat = chatDto.toEntity(senderName, Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul"))));

        chatService.createChatMessage(chat);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/sub/chatroom/" + chat.getChatRoomId(), chat);

        // Update sender's last_read_chat_id
        if (chatDto.getCrewId() != null && chatDto.getUserId() == null) { // Sender = crew
            updateCrewLastReadChatId(chatDto.getChatRoomId(), chatDto.getCrewId());
        } else { // Sender = user
            updateUserLastReadChatId(chatDto.getChatRoomId(), chatDto.getUserId());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(ResponseFormat.responseFormat(StatusCode.SUCCESS, ResponseMessage.SEND_SUCCESS_CHAT_MESSAGE, chat.getChatRoomId()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The code of the other person who implemented the function I wanted is different in logic, so I asked here myself because it would be difficult to follow.

When I asked chatGPT, I tried to proceed as below, but when I received a message from `/sub/chatroom/{chatRoomId}` subscription path, I wanted this code to be executed, but I couldn't print out the `"come in here!"` code at all.. I don't think it's mapped here at all...

```java
// /sub/chatroom/{chatroomId} 
    @SubscribeMapping("/sub/chatroom/{chatRoomId}")
    public void receiveChatMessage (
            @DestinationVariable("chatRoomId") String chatRoomId,
            @RequestHeader("crewId") Integer crewId,
            @RequestHeader("userId") Integer userId
    ) {
        System.out.println("come in here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        // Update Receiver's last_read_chat_id
        if (crewId != null && userId == null) { // Sender = crew
            updateCrewLastReadChatId(Integer.parseInt(chatRoomId), crewId);
        } else { // Sender = user
            updateUserLastReadChatId(Integer.parseInt(chatRoomId), userId);
        }
    }
```